# How to apply jquery on only new textarea form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have:

1 button to create new textarea form with same ID like old textarea form

```
<textarea class="message" id="edit"></textarea>
```

1 function to apply SimpleMDE - Markdown Editor for textarea form

```
function() {
    $(".message").each(function(t, e) {                
        new SimpleMDE({ element: $("#edit")[0] });
    })
}
```

So when i create new form, this jquery will apply for all textarea form with ID="edit", then old form will duplication

How can i apply jquery for only new textarea form?

Comment: `same ID like old textarea` That is wrong. Id should be unique.

Comment: You should only have one id='edit'. Try doing this with a class instead

Answer (score 1):

Rule of thumb - If you want to apply anything on a specific element on a page - use id. Because ids are (should always be) unique per page. No two ids should be the same in a page. Ids are like passport number - Always unique

If you want to apply anything to a set of elements on a page - use classes.

So the question you asked is itself not correct. Please make sure you don't have two same id's.

Hope this be of some help.

Happy Learning

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @jcubic, this is answer:

```
$(".message").each(function(t, e) {
    if (!this.processed) {
        new SimpleMDE({ element: this });
        this.processed = true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
    $(".message").each(function(t, e) {
        if (!this.processed) {
            new SimpleMDE({ element: this });
            this.processed = true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: @LãoCòi don't forget to mark the answer if it solve your problem.

Comment: This is not the right way to solve the answer. The question itself is wrong. Please try to guide it in the correct direction rather than just solving the problem